# JQuery returns blank text for an element

Tags: php, ajax

So im trying to recieve the text of an element for a specific ID. In my Javascript file Ih ave this code:

```
var amount = 2;
for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++)
{
    $("#b"+i).click(function() {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        var name = ($("#name"+i).text());
        alert(name);
```

It keeps alerting a blank. Heres my php file:

```
echo "<td id= \"name".$counter."\">".$values[$counter]."</td>
<td><button id=    \"b".$counter."\">Show Table</button></tr>";
$counter++;
```

The counter basically is 0 and 1. However whenever i try to get the text at name+i it returns a blank. does anyone know the problem with this?

Comment: Make sure `$values[$counter]` is defined. Also, can we see some rendered HTML?

Comment: Paste the html that get generates after your page, means the html code you see inside the browser after inspect element or right click

Comment: Use [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a closure issue, the value of `i` will be 2 when you click handler is fired. You can prevent this by passing the counter as a parameter to the click event.

```
var amount = 2;
for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++)
{
    $("#b"+i).click(i, function(e) {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        var name = ($("#name"+e.data).text());
        alert(name);
```